# Bokeh datatable in-cell edition - error in bokeh-tables-0.12.15.js?

Tags: python, datatable, bokeh

I'm just trying to get a working example where I can edit values of a datatable directly into cells.

I'm getting JS errors, but unfortunately I don't understand anything about JS :/

Here is the code used to reproduce error :

```
from bokeh.plotting import show, curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets.tables import DataTable, TableColumn, BooleanFormatter, CheckboxEditor
from bokeh.models.widgets.tables import NumberFormatter, NumberEditor, IntEditor, TextEditor, StringEditor, StringFormatter

# DataTable construction
dico = dict(
    nom=["Abathur", "Tychus", "Nova"],
    alive=[False] * 3,
    age=[x for x in range(0, 3)])
source_dt = ColumnDataSource(data = dico)
columns = [
    TableColumn(field="nom", title="Nom", editor=StringEditor(), formatter=StringFormatter()),
    TableColumn(field="alive", title="Alive", editor=CheckboxEditor(), formatter=BooleanFormatter(icon="check")),
    TableColumn(field="age", title="Age", formatter=NumberFormatter(), editor=IntEditor())
]
dt = DataTable(width=400, height=600, source=source_dt, columns=columns, editable=True, selectable=True)

# show(dt)

curdoc().add_root(dt)
```

Here is a screenshot of the datatable where I try to change a String/text value: [image]

And when I validate with enter-key or clicking somewhere else, datatable is frozen and I get an error from JS console in firefox : [image]

Same observations with chrome, the error from JS console in chrome : [image]

Working environnment is Windows 10, python 3.6 and bokeh 0.12.15 supplied by Anaconda, webbrowser firefox 59 or chrome 65
Also tested on debian 8 with bokeh provided by fresh anaconda installation

Am I doing something wrong ? Do you have a working sample where a value of a datatable is editable in the cell ?

**EDIT :** 
I was able to locate the line of code which raise the error, it is in file https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-0.12.15.js at line 13440

```
var validationResults = currentEditor.validate();
if (validationResults.valid) {                    <<---- RAISE THE ERROR
```

For a reason that escape me, `currentEditor.validate();` doesn't return anything and `validationResults` is still `undefined`

I also test the data_tables.py from github examples https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/models/file/data_tables.py and I get same result

Answer (score 0):

I finally manage to find the issue : 
On file https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-0.12.15.js 
line 118 must be changed

```
// OLD not working code
CellEditorView.prototype.validate = function () {
        this.validateValue(this.getValue());
    };

// NEW working code
CellEditorView.prototype.validate = function () {
        return this.validateValue(this.getValue());  <<---- added "return"
    };
```

With this modification, I am now able to edit cells content from datatables.

I opened a github issue to let competent people to solve it correctly https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7768